# How do I use a forEach loop to append a new div to each class?

Tags: javascript

After my .content div I am creating a new div with the class .details. This is only applies to the first instance of the .content div though, how do I add the .details div after each .content div on the page?

I believe I need to use a foreach loop, but I'm not sure how to implement it

Any help would be appreciated

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/BaQbNvZ) has full javascript code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid2">
      <div class="grid2__item">
        this is some content 1
        <div class="product">
            <img class="product__img" src=""> 
            <div class="product__bg"></div>
            <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
            <h3 class="product__subtitle"></h3>
            <p class="product__description"></p>
            <div class="product__price"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid2">
      <div class="grid2__item">
        this is some content 2
        <div class="product">
            <img class="product__img" src=""> 
            <div class="product__bg"></div>
            <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
            <h3 class="product__subtitle"></h3>
            <p class="product__description"></p>
            <div class="product__price"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid2">
      <div class="grid2__item">
        this is some content 3
        <div class="product">
            <img class="product__img" src=""> 
            <div class="product__bg"></div>
            <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
            <h3 class="product__subtitle"></h3>
            <p class="product__description"></p>
            <div class="product__price"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
window.onload = function () {

  {
    class Details {
      constructor() {
        this.DOM = {};

        const detailsTmpl = `
            <div class="details__bg details__bg--up"></div>
            <div class="details__bg details__bg--down"><p class="details__description"></p></div>
            <h2 class="details__title">title</h2>
            <div class="details__deco">deco</div>
            <h3 class="details__subtitle">subtitle</h3>
            `;


        this.DOM.details = document.createElement('div');
        this.DOM.details.className = 'details';
        this.DOM.details.innerHTML = detailsTmpl;
        DOM.content.appendChild(this.DOM.details);
      }
    }
    
     class Item {
      constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = {};
        this.DOM.el = el;
        this.DOM.product = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.product');
        this.DOM.productBg = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__bg');
        this.DOM.productImg = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__img');
        this.DOM.available = this.DOM.product.querySelectorAll('.available');
        // this.DOM.available = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.available');

        this.info = {
          img: this.DOM.productImg.src,
          title: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__title').innerHTML,
          subtitle: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__subtitle').innerHTML,
          // description: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__description').innerHTML,
        };

        this.initEvents();
      }
      open() {
        DOM.details.fill(this.info);
        DOM.details.open({
          productBg: this.DOM.productBg,
          productImg: this.DOM.productImg
        });
      }
      initEvents() {
        // ()=> has this equals to the above context
        this.DOM.available.forEach((item) => {
          // this references
          item.addEventListener('click', () => this.open());
        });
        // this.DOM.available.addEventListener('click', () => this.open());
      }

    };

    const DOM = {};
    DOM.grid = document.querySelector('.grid2');
    DOM.content = DOM.grid.parentNode;
    DOM.gridItems = Array.from(DOM.grid.querySelectorAll('.grid2__item'));
    let items = [];
    DOM.gridItems.forEach(item => items.push(new Item(item)));

    DOM.details = new Details();

  };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var findall_contentDiv = $('body').find(".container");
            if(findall_contentDiv.length > 0){
                var dynamic_div = "<div class='details'>"
                + "<div class='details__bg details__bg--up'></div>"
                + "<div class='details__bg details__bg--down'>"
                + "<p class='details__description'></p>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<h2 class='details__title'>title</h2>"
                + "<div class='details__deco'>deco</div>"
                + "<h3 class='details__subtitle'>subtitle</h3>"
                + "</div>"

                for (var i = 0; i < findall_contentDiv.length; i++) {
                    $(findall_contentDiv[i]).append(dynamic_div);
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="grid2">
                <div class="grid2__item">
                    this is some content 1
                    <div class="product">
                        <img class="product__img" src="">
                        <div class="product__bg"></div>
                        <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
                        <h3 class="product__subtitle"></h3>
                        <p class="product__description"></p>
                        <div class="product__price"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="grid2">
                <div class="grid2__item">
                    this is some content 2
                    <div class="product">
                        <img class="product__img" src="">
                        <div class="product__bg"></div>
                        <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
                        <h3 class="product__subtitle"></h3>
                        <p class="product__description"></p>
                        <div class="product__price"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="grid2">
                <div class="grid2__item">
                    this is some content 3
                    <div class="product">
                        <img class="product__img" src="">
                        <div class="product__bg"></div>
                        <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
                        <h3 class="product__subtitle"></h3>
                        <p class="product__description"></p>
                        <div class="product__price"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note: I use JQuery here for shorter coding. But this is the idea you may looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a forEach loop on your `.content` selector, I used querySelectorAll to return a nodeList. Then create a DIV with the class of `details` and insert this before the first child of your `.content` element, `div.insertBefore(details,div.children[0])` this will give you a div after `.content` and before `.grid`.

- ***If you only want this to happen on the first `.content` on the page you can use `cont.querySelector('.content') and it will only affect the first instance of the` .content` class it finds in the DOM.***

RETURNS:

[image: HTML Content]

```js
const cont = document.querySelectorAll('.content')
const createDivs = (el) => {
  el.forEach((div, i) => {
    // create a div to hold your HTML for each instance of .content 
    let details = document.createElement('DIV')
    // add the details class to each newly created div
    details.classList.add('details')
    // insert the newly created div 'details' into the DOM before the 
    // first child of the parent element 'div' which is the value of
    // each forEach loop of the cont selector
    div.insertBefore(details, div.children[0])
    details.innerHTML = '<div class="details__bg details__bg--up"></div><div class="details__bg details__bg--down"><p class="details__description"></p></div><h2 class="details__title">title</h2><div class="details__deco">deco</div><h3 class="details__subtitle">subtitle</h3>'
  })
}

createDivs(cont)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid2">
      <div>
        this is some content 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid2">
      <div>
        this is some content 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid2">
      <div>
        this is some content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




After my .content div I am creating a new div with the class .details. This is only applies to the first instance of the .content div though, how do I add the .details div after each .content div on the page?
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Dale. I'm not sure the code you provided would work in my existing Javascript code though?